# Entity Framework Code First & Search Criteria

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-first

So I have a model created in Entity Framework 4 using the CTP4 code first features.  This is all working well together.

I am attempting to add an advanced search feature to my application.  This "advanced search" feature simply allows the users to enter multiple criteria to search by.  For example:

**Advanced Product Search**

- Name
- Start Date
- End Date

This would allow the user to search by the product name and also limit the results by the dates that they were created.

The problem is that I do not know how many of these fields will be used in any single search.  How then can my Entity Framework query be constructed?

I have [an example](http://www.thegrubbsian.com/2008/12/01/dynamic-expressions-with-linq-to-entities/) describing how to create a dynamic query for Entity Framework, however this does not seem to work for the POCO classes I created for Code First persistence.

What is the best way for to construct a query when the number of constraints are unknown?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So after some hours of work on this problem (and some help from our friend Google) I have found a workable solution to my problem. I created the following Linq expression extension:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace MyCompany.MyApplication
{
    public static class LinqExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
        {
            if (condition)
                return source.Where(predicate);
            else
                return source;
        }
    }
}
```

This extension allows for a Linq query to be created like this:

```
var products = context.Products.WhereIf(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name), p => p.Name == name)
                               .WhereIf(startDate != null, p => p.CreatedDate >= startDate)
                               .WhereIf(endDate != null, p => p.CreatedDate <= endDate);
```

This allows each WhereIf statement to only affect the results if it meets the provided condition.  The solution seems to work, but I'm always open to new ideas and/or constructive criticism.

Comment: we can use in-buil where().where() but why should some one use your extension? what is so special there?

Answer (score 0):

John,

Your solution is absolutely awesome! But, just to share, I have been using this method above until I see your ideia.

```
var items = context.Items.Where(t => t.Title.Contains(keyword) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword));
```

So, it seems not to be the best solution for this, but for sure it is a way around.

Comment: if the goal is to prevent an error using !String.IsNullOrEmpty() then you should either put that in an if that encloses the var or put that first where it is used. If the value is coming from a [Required] model field.. it will never be NULL or Empty