# LINQ to Entities - Left outer join with a conditional where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have this project set up with EF4 and I'm using LINQ to Entities to form queries.

I'm having some trouble with a query that involves lots of conditional where clauses and several left outer joins.

I have partially solved the conditional where clauses with the following extension method (which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970723/entity-framework-code-first-search-criteria)).

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
    {
        if (condition)
            return source.Where(predicate);
        else
            return source;
    }
```

The problem I have now is that LINQ to Entities doesn't recognize the extension method when I use it on the joined tables.

Here's a part of the query:

```
from p in context.Entities.OfType<Patient>()
    .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name), p => p.Name.Contains(name))
from c in context.Contacts
    .Where(cp => cp.EntityID == p.EntityId).DefaultIfEmpty()
    .WhereIf(timestamp != null, c => c.Timestamp > timestamp)
```

I say partially solved because it works just fine the first time (patient name) in this query, but the second time (timestamp) it gives me this error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[x.Contact] WhereIf[Contact](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[x.Contact], Boolean, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[x.Contact,System.Boolean]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

So, I'm wondering if anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that EF is unable to recognize `WhereIf` inside a `SelectMany`. Rewriting your query into method syntax yields something like this (query is incomplete):

```
context.Entities.OfType<Patient>()
  .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name), p => p.Name.Contains(name))
  .SelectMany(
    p => context.Contacts
      .Where(cp => cp.EntityID == p.EntityId).DefaultIfEmpty()
      .WhereIf(timestamp != null, c => c.Timestamp > timestamp),
    (p, c) => new { p, c }
  )
```

The problem is the last `WhereIf`. You should be able to move it outside the `SelectMany`:

```
context.Entities.OfType<Patient>()
  .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name), p => p.Name.Contains(name))
  .SelectMany(
    p => context.Contacts
      .Where(cp => cp.EntityID == p.EntityId).DefaultIfEmpty(),
    (p, c) => new { p, c }
  )
  .WhereIf(timestamp != null, x => x.c.Timestamp > timestamp)
```

You can inspect the resulting SQL to see if you get what you actually want by casting the query into `ObjectQuery` and calling the method `ToTraceString`:

```
var query = context.Entities.OfType<Patient>() ...
Console.WriteLine(((ObjectQuery) query).ToTraceString());
```

Comment: This worked. The trick was indeed to move the WhereIf out of the SelectMany. I tried running the generated SQL just to confirm, and it produced the desired result. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Why not do `Where(timestamp == null || c.Timestamp > timestamp)`?