# EF Conditional Join Or WHERE IN

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am converting a stored procedure that implements pretty standard search functionality to Entity Framework code, and am not quite sure how to accomplish what this bit of SQL is doing:

```
SELECT 
    *    
FROM 
    MyTable a
WHERE  
    @parameter1 = 0 OR a.Id IN 
        (
            SELECT ot.Id FROM OtherTable ot 
            WHERE ot.Id = @parameter1 
            AND (@parameter2 = 0 OR ot.OtherValue = @parameter2)
        )
```

So essentially, some optional search parameters are passed in, and they are used as filters if they are non-zero.  Pretty standard.

On the case above, there is a M:1 relationship, with OtherTable being on the "many" side.

I see two options, but I can't seem to get the right syntax for either:

(1) I could simulate what is being done in the SP with a conditional Where
   clause ([Example Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970723/entity-framework-code-first-search-criteria)).  I tried something like this:

```
.WhereIf(search.Id != 0, mytable => search.AttributeId == mytable.OtherTables)
```

This would have to be filtered further for @parameter2.  But in any case, mytable.OtherTables is a collection since it is on the "many" side, so I can't use (for example) mytable.OtherTables.Id.

(2) I could convert this to a join, but the join would have to be conditional (only include the join if @parameter1 != 0).  I'm not sure if joining conditionally is possible with L2S/EF.

Answer (score 2):

How about conditionally adding the `Where` and only sending the relevant bits to SQL, rather than sending everything to SQL and trying to write a complicated query.

Remember, Linq uses deferred execution, which allows us to build up our query piece by piece, then execute it when we are ready.

```
IQueryable<MyTable> myTableQuery = context.MyTables.AsQueryable();

if (parameter1 != 0)
{
    IQueryable<OtherTable> otherTableQuery = context.OtherTables.AsQueryable();

    if (parameter2 != 0)
    {
        otherTableQuery = otherTableQuery.Where(ot => OtherValue = parameter2);
    }

    myTableQuery = myTableQuery.Where(mt => otherTableQuery.Any(ot => ot.Id = mt.Id));
}

return myTableQuery.ToList();
```

Please excuse any typos, this was composed in browser.